# cd/dvd rom drive continuouly searched

Tags: cd-drive

I am using 14.04 on HP630 Laptop for around 2 months now. From the beginning I have noticed that I **get a kind of clicking noise** from cd/dvd rom drive every 15 to 30 seconds even though **the drive is empty**.

I am sure the OS is sniffing the drive for any cd or dvd. Though the noise is very mild I can hear it every now and then.

Now how do I stop it and resolve the issue. I am sure every time it searches the drive the pivot motor rotates and the lens moves up and down. By this the physical wear and tear of the drive will be faster and the life comes down considerably, added to increased power consumption of the system.

Kindly help me.

Prasad G R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is called "polling", and is most likely caused by `udisks`.

Try: `udisks --inhibit-polling /dev/sr0` (replace `/dev/sr0` with the name of your device, if necessary.)

If it helps, you can ask `udisks` to permanently stop polling the device with a `udev` rule like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="*YOUR_DEVICE_MODEL*", ENV{UDISKS_DISABLE_POLLING}="1"
```

Create a file such as `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-no-polling.rules` and add the above rule to it, replacing `YOUR_DEVICE_MODEL` with the actual model string.

To find your model number, look at the output of `udisks --show-info /dev/sr0`.

The side effect is that you'll need to mount the optical media manually afterwards.

Comment: @PrasadGR Please take a look here on accepting answers and why it benefits the community: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work